# Set Shape .OnAction results in 1004 error: Application-defined or object-defined error

Tags: excel, vba

I've been trying to solve this error all morning and can't get a handle on it.  It looks like Excel really just doesn't want me to set the OnAction property of this shape.

The shape is part of a group of other rectangles/text boxes.

The code works on a non-grouped shape.

- workbook has no locked content
- no external macros or anything, both functions in same module

```
    Function Macro1()

    MsgBox (ActiveSheet.Shapes("box").OnAction)  'Returns the current OnAction string, as expected.

    ActiveSheet.Shapes("box").OnAction = "'WorksheetName'!Macro2"  '1004 error occurs here

    End Function
```

I've tried setting it to "Macro2"  , Macro2  , saving it as a string prior to the OnAction line, and even just trying to set it to an empty string "".  No dice.

Comment: So the `Macro2` is in the *sheet* code module and not a regular module?

Comment: It is in the same module as Macro1.  Not in the Sheet.

Comment: Then why do you have `'WorksheetName'!` included?

Comment: I get the same 1004 error if I omit 'WorksheetName!'

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce based on the details you've provided.

Comment: Edited my original.  could it have to do with the fact that the shape is in a Group?

Comment: That seems like it might be an important detail.

Comment: Ok, can reproduce the error. Surprisingly enough, it doesn't occur when you refer to the shape by index and not by name.

Comment: I came up with an answer, thanks for your assistance.  Just needed someone else to look at it and poke me in the right direction. :)

Answer (score 0):

***SOLVED.*** The group shape interferes with the individual shape properties. The following works to break the group, edit the shape, then regroup:

```
Function Macro1()
    With ActiveSheet
        .Shapes("Home").Ungroup
        .Shapes("box").OnAction = "Macro2"
        With .Shapes.Range("box").Regroup
            .Name = "Home"
        End With
    End With
End Function
```